# CKAN error after enabling harvester module - 'module' object has no attribute 'ITranslation'

Tags: python, module, ckan

After enabling the harvester module for CKAN, I'm getting the following error in **ckan_default.error.log** (and the web application returns status 500 until I disable the harvest and ckan_harvester plugins from config file):

```
mod_wsgi (pid=1605): Target WSGI script '/etc/ckan/default/apache.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
mod_wsgi (pid=1605): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/etc/ckan/default/apache.wsgi'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/etc/ckan/default/apache.wsgi", line 9, in <module>
    application = loadapp('config:%s' % config_filepath)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.6/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 247, in loadapp
    return loadobj(APP, uri, name=name, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.6/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 272, in loadobj
    return context.create()
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.6/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 710, in create
    return self.object_type.invoke(self)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.6/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 146, in invoke
    return fix_call(context.object, context.global_conf, **context.local_conf)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.6/site-packages/paste/deploy/util.py", line 56, in fix_call
    val = callable(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/config/middleware.py", line 58, in make_app
    load_environment(conf, app_conf)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/config/environment.py", line 232, in load_environment
    p.load_all(config)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/plugins/core.py", line 134, in load_all
    load(*plugins)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/plugins/core.py", line 148, in load
    service = _get_service(plugin)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/plugins/core.py", line 254, in _get_service
    return plugin.load()(name=plugin_name)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2355, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2361, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckanext-harvest/ckanext/harvest/plugin.py", line 31, in <module>
    class Harvest(p.SingletonPlugin, DefaultDatasetForm, DefaultTranslation):
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckanext-harvest/ckanext/harvest/plugin.py", line 43, in Harvest
    p.implements(p.ITranslation, inherit=True)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ITranslation'
```

I found some similar errors but not for CKAN and 'ITranslation', any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Commenting the following lines in **/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckanext-harvest/ckanext/harvest/plugin.py** make the server able to start with the harvest plugin:

_if p.toolkit.check_ckan_version(min_version='2.5.0'):
    p.implements(p.ITranslation, inherit=True)_

Comment: What CKAN version are you currently using?

Comment: I'm using CentOS 6.7 / Python 2.6.6 / CKAN 2.5.0a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it! Just upgraded current 2.5.0a installation to latest DEV version (2.6.0a) and it worked without problems...

Thanks!